# How to return only Tuesday and Thursday date from current given date

Tags: formula-field

I am using a process builder to create task whenever Lead is created . For Task Due Date I want to set always Thursday or Tuesday.  Means if I am creating task today (**Thursday**), then due date should be **today**.. If I am creating task tomorrow (**Friday**) then the due date should be **Tuesday**.. if I am creating task on **Wednesday** then the due date should be on **Thursday**. It will always what is the nearest date from today (Tuesday or Thursday).. I am trying with this formula, but not working

```
CASE( 
    WEEKDAY(TODAY()), 
    0, Today() + 2 , 1, Today() + 1 , 2, Today(), 3,
Today() + 1, 4, Today() , 5, Today() + 4, 6, Today() + 3,"Error"

)
```

Getting Error -

```
The formula expression is invalid: Incorrect parameter type for function 'CASE()'. Expected Date, received Text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're trying to return a Date value in the formula, you can't have a Text value of "Error" as the default.  You'll have to use a Date or NULL as the default.